# couldn't find an identity related to propositional logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I've got a question regarding proof of the statement below:

P^(PVQ) = P

I need the proof of this logical equivalence without using the truth table. My teacher suggested writing P as P V(or) 0 or P ^(and) 1 then go on and i did so, but couldn't make it the rest. Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Yes, the trick is that $P \equiv P \lor \bot$ [where $\bot$ is False, i.e. $0$ of boolean logic]: $(P \lor \bot) \land (P \lor Q) \equiv P \lor \bot$, and then use [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic)